# glob関数で取得したファイル名が文字化けする問題

Tags: php

失礼します。
特定の文字列を含む画像ファイルを表示する方法が分からず困っています。

文字列：01
画像ファイル名:xx_01_xxx.jpg

だとして、
文字列が01の時、画像ファイルxx_01_xxx.jpgを表示する
といった形です。

もし画像ファイル名に01が含まれていたら
というif文でのコードは考えたのですが、そもそも文字列から画像を指定するので違うと思いました。

追記：
試行錯誤したところ、glob関数を使って目的の動きを達成することができました。
しかし、文字列が文字化けしてしまったりする事があり安定しません。

コードはこちらです。

```
if(isset($code[0])){
    $code0 = substr($code[0], 3);
    $img0 = "img/".$code0."_*.jpg";
}
if(isset($code[1])){
    $code1 = substr($code[1], 3);
    $img1 = "img/".$code1."_*.jpg";
}
if(isset($code[2])){
    $code2 = substr($code[2], 3);
    $img2 = "img/".$code2."_*.jpg";
}
if(isset($img0)){
    foreach (glob($img0) as $val) {
        $i_img0 = $val;
    }
    print $i_img0;
}
if(isset($img1)){
    foreach (glob($img1) as $val) {
        $i_img1 = $val;
    }
    print $i_img1;
}
if(isset($img2)){
    foreach (glob($img2) as $val) {
        $i_img2 = $val;
    }
    print $i_img2;
}
```

$code[]の中身は5桁の数値になっています。
今の状態ですと、12120のコードで120を取得したくても20しか取得できない問題もあります。
12120だった場合、120と20のどちらかを柔軟に取得できるようにもしたいです。

ですがまずはファイル名が文字化けする問題からです。
文字化けしないものもありますので原因が分かりません。
何が問題になっているのでしょうか？

Comment: 「特定の文字列」はどのように与えられるのでしょうか。

Comment: `正規表現`を調べてみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: 「あるフォルダの中から特定の文字列を含むファイルを探し、そのファイル名を変数に得る」方法が知りたい、ということでしょうか。

Comment: h2s05さん：前のページからPOSTで持ってきたvalueの値を変数に格納したものが特定の文字列になります・
3100さん：調べてみます。
unaristさん：その通りです。

Comment: 文字化けの問題は文字化けしない場合があるということなので文字コードの非適合というわけではないのでしょう。環境・状況(OS,どのような文字列の場合に文字化けするかなど)が提示されていないのでよくわかりませんが、例えばシフトＪＩＳコードでの日本語文字には`\`(0x5)cが含まれる場合があり（例えば'表'）これがエスケープ文字として解釈されて誤動作を起こす場合があるのでそういう問題なのかもしれません。（未テスト）

Comment: @まふゆ 文字化けについては元の文字列が無いと判断しかねますので、文字化けするものと文字化けしないものを提示してもらう必要があります。 あと、`substr()` の第二引数は 切り出し開始位置の指定です。やるならこうですね。`substr($code,2)`

Comment: BLUEPIXYさん：文字コードについての知識が少ないので、いろいろ調べてみます。
Shironeさん：substrの使い方に気をつけたいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

今回の件に関しまして、皆様からの丁寧な回答により問題が解決しましたので回答とさせていただきます。

文字化けの件についてですが、文字コードの指定をUTF8にしていました。
自分の理想としてはUTF8で動かしたかったのですが、

> mb_convert_encoding関数

こちらを使用しUTF8をシフトJISに変換したところ文字化けが直りました。
UTF8でも文字化けしないようにするための知識もつけていけるように精進します。

今回もありがとうございました。